# How to remove microseconds from time field

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a time field which i have used;

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format= '%H:%M:%S.%f' ).dt.time
```

The output it is giving me is ;

10:52:01.671000

I need to get rid of the millisedconds and remain with only the H:M:S;

10:52:01

How can i do this. I have tried different options but cannot seem to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html#pandas.Series.dt.floor) to round down to the nearest second before `dt.time`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['10:52:01.671000', '10:18:18.91654']})

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.floor('S').dt.time
```

`df`:

```
       Time
0  10:52:01
1  10:18:18
```